# Puppeteer / Node.js - Submit login form > resubmit same login form when and only if redirected to resubmit form from main page. (redirect is random)

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

So I'm new to puppeteer/node/js so I need to read a lot of docs to become familiar but in the haze of it all it does not always obvious what and how to implement the correct method.

I have a sequence of events to navigate where I am stuck is section 2A of submitting the login form. Sometimes I am required to login just once. I can handle the logging in but sometimes I am redirected to a main page and on the next step (a button click after first login on the main page) I am redirected back to the login form again.

```js
    await page.goto("https://homepage/", {
      waitUntil: `networkidle2`,
    })

    // 1 - Go to User Login:  user login button - this works
    const [response] = await Promise.all([
      page.waitForNavigation({
        delay: randomGenerator * 200,
      }),
      page.click(`.access`, {
        waitUntil: `networkidle2`,
      }),
    ])

    // 2A - Login Page - this works 
    await page.type("#User", process.env.KEY, {
      delay: randomGenerator,
    })
    // password
    await page.type("#Pass", process.env.PASSWORD, {
      delay: randomGenerator,
    })

   // 3 - Login Submit Button - is good if main page does not redirect to step 2
    await page.click(`button[type=submission][name=submitBtn]`, {
      delay: randomGenerator,
    }),

   // 4 - this section sometimes redirects to step 2 Login Page
        await page.$(
     'div[id=mainPage][name=mainPage"]'
    ),

   // 5 - Below is the code that is not functioning. I tried to overcome the random 
      redirect. I tried 
      `waitForNavigation`  and  `waitForSelector`, perhaps I was on the 
      right track but not too sure. I get unknown value error when with  
      `waitForNavigation` and I am not handling `waitForSelector` would work 
       but gives error if there is not a login page.
   // 2B - Login Page attempt if redirected from main page
   // This step is not always enforced and when enforced follows step 3

      await page.waitForSelector("#User")
    if ((await page.$("#User")) !== null) {
      await page.type("#User", process.env.KEY, {
        delay: randomGenerator,
      })
      setInterval(
        await page.type("#Pass", process.env.PASSWORD, {
          delay: randomGenerator,
        }),
        2000
      )
    }
   `Error: waiting for selector #User failed: timeout 300`
```

Comment: Have you tried just checking if you are on the login page and then filling the form?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski - That is where I am an stuck. I've tried to use waitForSelector and fill the form if true but if in the case I am not redirected to the login page then how is that handled? (currently I getTimeout `Error: waiting for selector #User failed: timeout 300` ) Would I throw in an else if -> go to next step?

Comment: You can use `waitForNavigation` or `waitForTimeout` and then use `$()` for example. Or you can just handle the error with `try...catch`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Ok great and thank you. I will try to apply first thing tomorrow and follow up then.

Comment: Hard to help without the site.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Turns out the 1st time I tried to use `waitForNavigation` I camel cased the `networkidle ` option.  
No My 1st login works, the second login request after redirect does not. Any idea of what could be going on?
Call stack errors:
`waitForNavigation` error: `TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded`
`waitForSelector`  error: `Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[class=form-control[name=UserCode]' is not a valid selector`
`page.focus` error: `Error: No node found for selector: #UserCode`

Comment: `'[class=form-control[name=UserCode]'` this selector is missing `]` in the middle

Comment: @KonradLinkowski That was a typo in my comment, I have it written properly in my code.   I am required to login twice. First time is successful second is not. The new login page may use iFrames, I just am not sure. First check I do not see iFrame tags in the HTML